# Is there a way to specify file extension to the file saved to s3 by kinesis firehose

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am setting up a kinesis firehose stream and everything works well with the files getting created on s3 which are delimited. But i was wondering if there is a way to specify an extension to this file since the consumer of this file require it to be either a csv or txt. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to get an extension for the files generated by firehose but I ended up using data pipeline to do this by using the ShellCommandActivity component which allows one to run shell commands on the files in Amazon S3 and write the resulting files to either S3 or any other location that you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an s3 trigger to lambda and rename from there.